# Accessing CouchDB Futon on a remote server

Tags: ssh, couchdb, telnet

I've installed CouchDB on a remote server that I have access to through a terminal telnet/ssh client.

The server is running on CentOS6.

I really want to be able to work with Futon, but I cannot at the moment because I can only open localhost:5984 in the ssh client.

Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just create ssh tunnel to your remote CouchDB instance:

```
ssh -f -L localhost:15984:127.0.0.1:5984 user@remote_host -N
```

And after that your remote CouchDB Futon that still serve on localhost address will be available for you by address: `http://localhost:15984/_utils`. Replace local port 15984 by your choice.

P.S. There is also [awesome guide](http://library.linode.com/databases/couchdb/ssh-tunnel) from Linode wiki with example couchdb-tunnel script. Hope it helps.

Comment: I get this error in FUton: "Error: error
{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},
 [{couch_file,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}". Have you experienced that?

Comment: `eacces` error is about insufficient permissions for file operations. Have your `couchdb` used read/write permissions for his database/logs directory? See [p4.1](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL5#Building_CouchDB_from_source_.28with_EPEL_packages.29) for additional info.

Comment: Thanks again. Your a genius. Saved me a lot of time. Kudos. Have a nice day.

Comment: also check out autossh to maintain persistent ssh tunnels. http://www.debianadmin.com/autossh-automatically-restart-ssh-sessions-and-tunnels.html

Comment: wow! Didn't know you could do this; this opens up so many doors. Thx.

Comment: lovely! I've used the minGW shell on Windows to get the tunnel up and running, had to remove the -f option tho. http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: `Permission denied, please try again.` should I change something before I tunnel to my server couchdb?

Comment: How do I do this when my remote couchdb also has a username and password?  Usually I would connect with http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/_utils if it was local