# Remote access to couchDB not working

Tags: server, couchdb, ubuntu-server

I have a couchDB instance, running on my server.

Followed to the instructions on [couchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.5.0/config/http.html) i want to access the admin console of my couchdb from my pc, but it doesn't work.

I also restarted the couched after i changed the `/etc/couchdb/local.ini` file.

when i check the listening ports with:

`netstat -ntulp`

the output is:

`tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:5984  0.0.0.0:*  LiSTEN  -`

So actually it should be accessible, but it isn't.

What i have to do, that i can access my couchdb from remote?

CouchDB Version: 1.5.0

Server: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this Problem with the answer of this question: [Access CouchDB Futon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865024/accessing-couchdb-futon-on-a-remote-server)

I have only to create a ssh tunnel to my remote couchdb:

`ssh -f -L localhost:15984:127.0.0.1:5984 user@remote_host -N`